# Why does the C program give me this output when printing a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int i;
    int buf[10];
    char *p ;
    p = 4;
    printf("%d",p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 4

How come it is 4? I was expecting some address value. Can you please help me understand it?

Comment: Undefined behavior. Didn't you get some warnings?

Comment: You are getting the address value indeed - it's 4, as you have assigned it one line above the printf.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Compiler warnings exist for good reasons. Enable and pay heed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is undefined behavior, because `%d` expects an integer.

The reason why you see this output is that pointers have enough capacity to store small integer numbers, such as 4. If by coincidence the pointer size on your system matches the size of an integer, `printf` would find a representation that it expects at the location where it expects it, so it would print the numeric value of your pointer.

The proper way to print your pointer would be with the `%p` format specifier, and a cast:

```
printf("%p", (void*)p);
```

> I was expecting some address value.

You would get an address value if you had assigned `p` some address. For example, if you did this

```
char buf[10];
char *p = &buf[3];
printf("%p", (void*)p);
```

you would see the address of `buf`'s element at index 3.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/atvzII)

Comment: No undefined behavior in the actual conversion though, merely implementation-defined behavior. As we can see the program works fine, meaning no undefined behavior was ever invoked. 6.3.2.3. `An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.`  You'll only get UB in case any of these things does not hold. But in this case, for this particular compiler, they do. The printf format specifier invokes UB though.

Comment: @Lundin That's correct. I did not say that assigning 4 to a pointer was UB, only that the use of `%d` for printing that pointer was UB.